# Split Custom 'Field Name' on 2 lines

Tags: jira

We added new custom field and it name bigger then JIRA can display, so JIRA take first N characters and then add ...
f.x. I've field: 'My very very long field' will be transformed to 'My very very...'
Is it possible to split Name of 2 lines? f.x. 'My very very 
 long field' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following to the field description:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  AJS.$(document).ready(function() {
    AJS.$('#customfield_10108-val').parent().find('strong').css('height','34px').css('white-space','normal');
  });
</script>
```

change `customfield_10108-val` to your cf id. If it doesn't work, try to add it to the [`Announcement Banner`](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Configuring+an+Announcement+Banner)

Comment: it works if I execute code into console, but if I put code to Field description it does not work.

Comment: thanks, it is a solution for my case, however I will not use it :) to complicated in terms of support.

Answer (score 0):

Not easily. There are many places where a custom field name is displayed. Abbreviation is one way to go and then put the long name in the field's description.